# The bar doesn't display, can't follow the tutorial beginner developer

Tags: html, css, height

I tried to follow this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=27JtRAI3QO8) but I got stuck at minute 52:40. When he is giving the bar height and color, I do the same thing but it doesn't display. Can anyone help me? I would be grateful

```css
.skills__bar,
.skills__percentage
{   height: 5px;
    border-radius: .25rem;
}

.skills__bar{
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="skills__titles">
    <h3 class="skills__name">Photoshop</h3>
    <span class="skills__number">80%</span>
</div>
<div class="skills__bar">
    <span class="skills__percentage skills__psd"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> The color property specifies the color of the text. - [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_color.asp)

The property applied in the video is not a `color`, it's a `background-color`. Try this code below to see the result after you change the color property to background-color.

```css
.skills__bar,
.skills__percentage
{   height: 5px;
    border-radius: .25rem;
}

.skills__bar{
    background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="skills__titles">
    <h3 class="skills__name">Photoshop</h3>
    <span class="skills__number">80%</span>
</div>
<div class="skills__bar">
    <span class="skills__percentage skills__psd"></span>
</div>
```

*https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-color*